# How to create buttons to start and stop a JQuery News Ticker

Tags: jquery, html, xml, ajax, ticker

I am trying to make a news ticker using JQuery that cycles messages automatically, but can be stopped and started with buttons. So far I have the `<li>` messages that will cycle and repeat.

I am trying to use the following code to create the buttons mentioned above. The buttons are created, and the script function looks right to me.

```
Is there something I'm missing below?
```

Also, is there a feature that I can use to make the page refresh itself? In case someone manipulates the messages while the page is in use. If I don't take care of that, its fine I really am getting stumped on buttons.

Thank you for any help you can offer.

```
<!doctype html>

<head><meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>homework</title>
<link href="resources/css/global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">

</script>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IM+Fell+DW+Pica+SC' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<body>

<div id="page">

<ul id="ticker_01" class="ticker">

<li>1st block</li>
<li>2nd Block</li>
<li>Should be nearly finished</li>
<li>Finally done</li>
</ul>
</div>
<input type="button" class="next" value="next" />
<input type="button" class="prev" value="prev" />
<script>

function tick()
{
$('#ticker_01 li:first').slideUp( function () { $(this).appendTo($('#ticker_01')).slideDown(); });
}

setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 5000);
(function(){
var $lis = $('ul li');
var index = 0, lastIndex = 0;
start(); // activate first, add event listeners to buttons
function next(){
lastIndex = index;
if(++index == $lis.length) index = 0; // if next is out of bounds go to first
    $lis.eq(index).addClass('active');
    $lis.eq(lastIndex).removeClass('active');
};

function prev(){
    lastIndex = index;
    if(--index < 0) index = ($lis.length - 1); // if prev is less than first go to last
    $lis.eq(index).addClass('active');
    $lis.eq(lastIndex).removeClass('active');
};
function start(){
    $lis.eq(0).addClass('active');
    $('.next').click(next);
    $('.prev').click(prev);
}
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Is there a built-in button feature with JQuery` ?

Hardly Not ,but you have to look upon [**jQuery UI**](http://jqueryui.com/)

```
Also, is there a feature that I can use to make the page refresh itself?
```

**yes of course**  that's  **AJAX**

AJAX helps you to update what you want with out a real gaint refresh , simply update only what you want

Refer 
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: excellent, GREAT LINKS! I did however find a javascript code that will allow me to specify how often the page should refresh.
 
setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload(1);},20000);

Comment: sorry I just updated the code a little and want to see if there are any thoughts to making the buttons work properly.

Comment: it is bat to update the whole page using window.location.reload() tr AJAX